# Rashi: Caleb married Miriam

Tags: sources-mekorot, marriage, rashi, miriam

I remember reading a rashi on Chumash that quoted a Chazal (I believe [sota 12](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=18&daf=12&format=pdf)) that says that Caleb married Miriam. Anyone know where this rashi is

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try Rashi to Shemot [17:10](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9596&st=&pgnum=248) or [24:14](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9596&st=&pgnum=400).

Comment: You beat me to it, although I would have linked to Chabad's _Tanakh_ with Rashi, which has English translations, as well( and gives the source as Sotah 11b, where the _Ma'amar_ referred to begins).

Comment: @Tamir, no reason you can't do that in the comments here.

Comment: Oh, the dark days before @HodofHod's script. How did we survive...